# If $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$ is continuous, is it true $\lambda\mapsto \omega_\lambda$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $C^0(X)$ be the space of the continuous self-maps of $X$. Also, assume that $\Lambda$ is a compact metric space.

Consider a map $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$
and the map $\varphi:\Lambda\to C^0(X)$ defined by $\varphi(\lambda) := \omega_\lambda$, where $\omega_\lambda(x) := \omega(\lambda, x)$.

**In my research, I need to study relation between continuity of $\varphi$ and $\omega$.**

One can check that $\omega= F\circ (\varphi\times \mathrm{id}_X)$, where $F:C^0(X)\times X\to X$ defined by $F(f, x) :=f(x)$ is the evaluation map and $\mathrm{id}_X(x)=x$. It is known that  evaluation map $F$ is continuous if $X$ is locally compact and the topology on $C^0(X)$ is the compact-open topology.

Hence, if $X$ is locally compact and the topology on $C^0(X)$ is the compact-open topology, then continuity of $\varphi$ implies that $\omega$ is continuous.

What can say if $C^0(X)$ is the space of the continuous self-maps of $X$ with the $C^0$-metric given by:
$$d_{C^0}(f, g)= \sup _{x\in X}d(f(x), g(x))$$

Is is true that $(C^0(X), d_{C^0})$ is a topological space with the compact-open topology?

Comment: The function $d_{C^0}$ may not be finite-valued on $C^0(X)$, if $X$ is not compact. A boundedness assumption on the functions in $C^0(X)$ may be necessary to proceed (at least with classical metric space theory).

Comment: You need to tell us which topology you want to consider on $C^0(X)$ for the general case.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg In my research, $\Lambda$ is compact metric space , $(X, d)$ is locally compact and consider distance between $f, g:X\to X$ by $d_{C^0}(f, g)= \sup_{x\in X} d(f(x), g(x))$.

Comment: I need to know relation between continuity of $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$ and $\varphi:\Lambda\to (C(X), d_{C^0})$ by $\varphi(\lambda)= \omega_\lambda$, where $\omega_\lambda:X\to X$ is defined by $\omega_\lambda(x)= \omega(\lambda, x)$.

Comment: Have you read Theo's comment? The definition of the metric is not well-defined.

Comment: By This comment, I must consider $X$ as a compact metric space if we consider $d_{C^0}$ on $C(X)$. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $d_{C^0}$ only works if all functions in $C^0(X)$ are bounded with respect to $d$ (what is $d_{C^0}(f,0)$ for an unbounded $f$?)

Thus you must make additional assumptions, for example that $X$ is compact or that the metric $d$ is bounded. The latter is not a very hard restriction because each metric is equivalent to a bounded metric.

Let us now consider the more general case that we are given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a topological space $Y$. On the set of $d$-bounded continuous functions $BC^0(Y;X,d)$ from $Y$ to $X$ you can define a metric $d^+$ by $d^+(f,g) = \sup_{y \in Y} d(f(y),g(y))$.

Here are some well-known results which you can find for example in Chapter XII. 8 of

> JAMES DUGUNDJI, Topology. Allyn and Bacon. (Boston, 1966).

1. If neither $X$ nor $Y$ is compact, then for any bounded metric $d$ one has $BC^0(Y;X,d) = C^0(Y,X)$. The metric topology on this set depends not only on metric topology on $X$, but on the particular bounded metric $d$. The metric topologies induced by equivalent bounded metrics are in general distinct, and consequently in general distinct from  the compact-open topology.
2. If $X$ is compact, then $BC^0(Y;X,d) = C^0(Y,X)$ for any metric $d$. The metric topology on $C^0(Y,X)$ only depends on the metric topology on $X$, but it is in general distinct from the compact-open topology.
3. If $Y$ is compact, then $BC^0(Y;X,d) = C^0(Y,X)$ and the metric topology on $C^0(Y,X)$ agrees with the compact-open topology.